# Django CreateView allows resubmission of the data when the form is displayed when hiting the back button

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to make an app with an upload image. The thing is that I want to limit the possibility of uploading an image to only once per day. Everything is working fine except if the user is using the back button of the browser. He can spam the system. What is the correct way to prevent this?

models.py

```
# Admin option to select from
PHOTO_STATUS = (
    ('ir', 'In Review'),
    ('ap', 'Approved'),
    ('tr', 'Trash'),
)

def pause():
    return timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(minutes=5)


# Main photo upload app
class PhotoUpload(models.Model):
    '''After the user finishes the challenge
    he can upload a photo using this app'''
    # The date when a user uploads a photo
    date_upload = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # The date when user can upload another photo

    # pause = date_upload + timezone.timedelta(minutes=20)
    pause_upload = models.DateTimeField(default=pause)
    # The status of the photo
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='ir', choices=PHOTO_STATUS)
    # The date when the admin aproves the photo
    date_approved = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,
                                         blank=True,
                                         null=True)
    # The date when the admin soft-deletes the photo
    date_deleted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    # A function that defines the path where the photo
    # will be uploaded and that will change the filename.
    def path_and_rename(instance, filename):
        extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
        if User.is_authenticated:
            # print(instance._user.username)
            return 'uploads/{}-{}.{}'.format(instance.user.username,
                                             instance.date_upload,
                                             extension)
        else:
            return 'uploads/{}.{}'.format(instance.date_upload, extension)

    # Application side file size check
    def file_size(value):
        limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024
        if value.size > limit:
            raise ValidationError(
                'File too large. Size should not exceed 2 MB.')

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename,
                              validators=[file_size],
                              null=True,
                              blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pause_upload)
```

view

```
class PhotoUploadCreate(CreateView):
    model = PhotoUpload
    template_name = 'upload_photo.html'
    form_class = PhotoUploadForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(PhotoUploadCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('success')
```

Thank you!

**Edit**
Here is my template where I use a template tag called **photos** and a template filter called **elapsed**.

```
{% for photo in photos %}

    <div class="container vertical-centre">

        {% if not photo.pause_upload|elapsed:1 %}

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="centre-colour">
                        {% if photo.user.first_name %}{{ photo.user.first_name }}{% else %}{{ photo.user.username }}{% endif %} you can upload another photo anytime after:<br>
                            <div id="clockdiv" class="centre-colour">
    <span class="hours"></span> Hours <span class="minutes"></span> minutes 
    <span class="seconds"></span> seconds
</div>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% else %}

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="centre-colour">
                        CONGRATULATIONS {% if photo.user.first_name %}{{ photo.user.first_name }}{% else %}{{ photo.user.username }}{% endif %}!!!
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="centre-colour">
                       Upload photo:
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">  
                    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                        {% crispy form %}
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <h4 class="centre-colour">or</h4>
                    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" role="button" id="goHome" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Start again</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And here are the template tag and filter

```
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('photos/photos_tags.html')
def photos_up(request, number=1):
    a = PhotoUpload.objects.filter(user__username=request).exists()
    if a:
        return {'form': PhotoUploadForm(),
                'photos': PhotoUpload.objects.filter(
                    user__username=request
        ).order_by(
                    '-pause_upload')[:number]
        }
    else:
        return {'form': PhotoUploadForm(),
                'photos': PhotoUpload.objects.all()[:number]
                }

register = template.Library()
@register.filter(expects_localtime=True)
def elapsed(time, seconds):
    return time + timezone.timedelta(seconds=seconds) < timezone.now()
```

Everything is working as expected unless a user decides to hit the back button from the **success** page. Then the **upload** page will go again into the form view instead to go to the counter.

Comment: You can save the timestamp of the last uploaded image and disable uploads if the time delta (with the current time) is less than one day.

Comment: You can consider rate limit the access... here is one possible plugin https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0/

Comment: @utkbansal Thank you for your comment. Please see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an attribute in your database as `lastuploaded (DateTimeField)` and when user uploads a photo check that if `lastuploaded` is one day before current time.
EDIT: 
add a lastuploaded field to your model.

```
class PhotoUpload(models.Model):
    last_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)
```

Now in your view's form_valid function put a check.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        photo_upload_object = PhotoUpload.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).latest('last_uploaded')
        if photo_upload_object.last_uploaded + datetime.datetime.timedelta(days=1) < current_time and photo_upload_object.last_uploaded is not None:
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            return super(PhotoUploadCreate, self).form_valid(form)
        else: 
            return HttpResponse("some error")
```

Other approach might be to save last uploaded in cookies but that won't work in all cases like login from different devices.

Comment: why are you making this with template tags. When upload request from user comes to your server check `current_time > UserObject.lastuploaded + 1 day`  (pseudo code). and don't any datetime field in your template for this purpose. It will be redundant.

Comment: I'm a beginner and I founded to be easier to make the logic in a template tag rather than in CreateView.  I know this doesn't respect the DRY concept but it was the only thing that worked. And is working except when a user hits the back button. Before deployment I will make a code refactoring.

Comment: the above solution is pure backend solution so user can do whatever he want but if he has uploaded a photo then he will only be able to upload after one day. Don't use template tags it will just make things complex for you as beginner.

Comment: Can you please show me where to put that code and how?

Comment: the above edit will give you a gist about the approach

Comment: Thank you very much!
Can HttpResonse return a template?